# How to Merge multidimensional array with its own sub array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

plz anyone help me. I want to merge the subarrays. 
I have associative array to merge in php like below.but the arrays were flatter. I tried to adapt the code, but unfortunately without success.
**Here my example :**

```
Array(
 [0] => Array(
        [1] => Array(
                [pid] => 1278
                [price] => 30
            )
        [2] => Array (
                [pid] => 1279
                [price] => 300
            )
    )
    [1] => Array (
        [1] => Array (
                [pid] => 1280
                [price] => 120
            ) 
        [2] => Array (
                [pid] => 1281
                [price] => 250
            )
)
```

And i have to Generate like below.

```
Array (
    [1] => Array (
            [pid] => 1278
            [price] => 30
        )
    [2] => Array (
            [pid] => 1279
            [price] => 300
        )
    [3] => Array (
            [pid] => 1280
            [price] => 120
        )
    [4] => Array (
            [pid] => 1281
            [price] => 250
        )
)
```

Comment: point a new variable to the top level array first index, than newvars contains what you want
    
   `$newvar = $array[0];`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Try this

```
$a = array(
   array(
      1 => array(
            'pid' =>  1234
            'price' => 200
         )
      2 => array(
            'pid' =>  1234
            'price' => 200
         ) 
    ),
    array(
      1 => array(
            'pid' =>  1234
            'price' => 200
         )
      2 => array(
            'pid' =>  1234
            'price' => 200
         ) 

    );
$a = call_user_func_array('array_merge',$a);
print_r($a);
```